# Shortest length of wire required to connect points

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-points

> > There are 2 sets , $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3..... ,a_n\} $ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3.. b_n\}$ . All elements of these sets are real numbers. Each point in set $A$ need to be connected to one and only one point in set $B$ . How must we connect to use shortest length of wire??

I know the answer is take the smallest element in $A$ and connect to smallest element in $B$ , then do so for second-smallest ones and so on..  I was trying to proof it . I tried using induction.. I also tried trying to decompose other possible  connections to the one that is the solution.. but I failed.. miserably.

Comment: How do you connect two real numbers "via lengths of wire?"  Are you asking for some permutation $\pi\in S_n$ such that the summation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |a_i - b_{\pi(i)}|$ is minimized?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri:  Notice that the sets have the same number of elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, exactly.. you are right. :)

Comment: I'll assume $a_1$ and $b_1$ are the smallest elements of $A$ and $B$. If you have some wiring solution where they are not connected, then $a_1$ connects to $b_u$ and $a_v$ connects to $b_1$ for some $u$ and $v$. Show that if you swap the connections to $a_1-b_1$ and $a_v-b_u$ then the total length of wire cannot increase. So to get an optimal solution, you can assume without loss of generality that $a_1$ and $b_1$ are connected. Then induction takes care the rest, showing that the proposed solution is optimal. It is not always the only optimal solution, but is the only general solution.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you very mcuh